# how to rephrase the sentences below?

Tags: grammar

I have found A,B,and C through Google books. I am wondering if I have correctly rephrased them? Would you please correct me? especially B and A.

"Is my rephrasing ***grammatically*** sound?

A. The last competitor to finish took more than 2 hours.

B. She was a good student, finishing in half the time it took the others to finish.

C. What normally took me a week to finish took three months.

**Revised** ***A***. To finish took the last competitor more than 2 hours.

**Revised** ***B***. ...finishing in half the time to finish took the others.

**Revised** ***C***. It took three months to finish what normally too me a week.

Thanks

Comment: A sounds off, B sounds wrong, C sounds OK, excepting the typo (too->took).

Comment: It would help to know what you mean by "correctly rephrased." Do you mean, "Am I interpreting the original sentence correctly?" Or do you mean, "Is my rephrasing grammatically sound?" Your question could mean either one, but the answers won't necessarily be the same – you can get one part right and the other part wrong.

Comment: A) *It took the last competitor more than 2 hours to finish.* (Sander's version is also fine) B) *She was a good student, finishing in half the time the others took to finish.* (same as Sander's fix) C) *It took (me) three months to finish what normally took (me) a week.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence A definitely sounds odd. It is not at all idiomatic. I would rephrase it to:

> **It** took the last the last competitor to finish more than 2 hours.

The *to finish* modifies *the last competitor*, not *took*. In this sentence it does not imply a difference in meaning, though in other cases it might. However, because it is this *competitor* that is being modified and not the verb, it needs to stick to the *competitor* and you cannot place the phrase *to finish* in initial position (at the start of your sentence).

Sentence B also sounds really odd. You should rephrase it like so:

> ...finishing in half the time the others took to finish.

Still, the original sentence is more idiomatic than this rephrased version.

Sentence C sounds alright, except for the typo.